# PyQt4: QFileDialog and QFontDialog localization

Tags: localization, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

Subj: is it possible? For example, can I translate `QtGui.QFileDialog().getSaveFileName()` button "Save" to "Conservare", and "Cancel" to "Ignorare"? Is it possible to create my class based on `QFileDialog/QFontDialog` without inventing a velocity?
Someone said that these functions will be always translated, depending os system locale. Don't believe, my Russian version of OpenSUSE says that it is a lie. :-) And Russian Windows 7 has a such behaviour. All strings which I see on my systems are English. I'm not a nationalist, but I want to use strings in other languages. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard Qt installation should include 20 or so translation files for the Qt library itself. These files can be found at runtime by using [QLocale](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html) and [QLibraryInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibraryinfo.html) to construct the arguments used by [QTranslator.load](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load). Further details can be found in [this section](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html#producing-translations) of the Qt i18n docs.

Here's a basic PyQt4 example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.buttons = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        button = self.buttons.addButton(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Open)
        button.clicked.connect(self.handleOpen)
        button = self.buttons.addButton(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Close)
        button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttons)

    def handleOpen(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
        dialog.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        locale = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        locale = QtCore.QLocale.system().name()
    name = 'qt_%s' % locale
    path = QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)
    if translator.load(name, path):
        app.installTranslator(translator)
    else:
        print('ERROR: could not load translation file:'
              ' name=%r, path=%r' % (name, path))
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really useful. Only one question: can I use different translations (default Qt's and my own) together?

Comment: I have some elements in my app, translated via another qm file with QTranslator.translate.

Comment: @ghostmansd. Yes, you can install multiple translators. The look-up for translations is done in reverse order, so you probably want to install your own `qm` file _last_ (see [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#installTranslator)).

Answer (score 0):

I've already found a solution: **qm** files. You can get them from **ts** files, using `lrelease`.