# Is there an option to change the "Choose" button text of a QFileDialog permanently?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qfiledialog

I open a QFileDialog to select a folder, nothing spectacular.
@eyllanesc already showed me how to create a delegate of the sideBar to rename the shortcuts based on QUrl's. Now I want to rename the "Choose" button in the FileDialog. I'm already capable to rename the "Cancel" button and the labels. But as he mentioned here:
[QFileDialog.getOpenFileName change button text from 'Open' to 'Remove'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656730/qfiledialog-getopenfilename-change-button-text-from-open-to-remove)
the "Choose" button will get to its old name when you step through the folders (when the TreeView is refreshed).
Is there an other option as he mentioned in the other topic to rename the button permanently?
Is it possible to create a delegate like he did with the sideBar here: [Is there an option to rename a QUrl/shortcut in a SideBar of a QFileDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284292/is-there-an-option-to-rename-a-qurl-shortcut-in-a-sidebar-of-a-qfiledialog/69290865#69290865) ?

Comment: It seems you are confused about what a delegate is (I strongly suggest you to patiently study the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes)): a delegate is an interface used by *item views* that is used to show the data of a model and allow interaction with it (usually, editing). A button is just a button.

Comment: @musicamante Conceptually speaking, a delegate seems quite apt, since it's just a helper object that carries out certain operations on behalf of another object. In this case, a simple QObject with an event-filter that handled paint-events would suffice. The painting could all be done by the style, with the button text being updated via the style-options.

Comment: @ekhumoro I was thinking about handling paint events indeed, but only as a "trigger" to check if the button text has changed, most importantly because changing the label drawing alone could result in unexpected behavior with mnemonics. In any case, I still believe that the concept of delegate (at least, in Qt-lingo, also considering the information provided and the related question) should *not* be considered in the same way. That said, conceptually, everything can be a delegate ;-)

Comment: @musicamante Yes, exactly my point - anything can be a delegate. In fact, I'm suggesting a delegate for a delegate ;-)

Comment: @mo_ses257 in any case, I'm not sure I understand your question: are you asking if there is *another* way?

Comment: @musicamante yes, is there another way to solve the problem that the button is ranamed back to the QT default value after every TreeView refresh? Isn't there an option to set the default values? I mean, what if I want to change it to another language? And if you're asking why I don't comment on that original topic, I have not enough "points" (50 I guess) to do that. That's why I opened a new question.

Comment: @mo_ses257 Qt includes translation files for the user-visible strings contained in its libraries (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9128966/984421)). For file-dialogs, the open/save button is provided by a [QDialogButtonBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html) which uses [standard-buttons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum) - which possibly explains why the text cannot be modified in the same way as the labels. Of course, if you change any of these, you will have to provide your own translations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dig myself into it using my own qm file.